# what does the dot in the following emacs command mean

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Here is some doco I'm creating but...

I'm not sure what the dot '.' between the extension and the mode is
for though in the following:

---

## File Associations

*Example:* Associate `*.mmd` with `markdown-mode`:

```
      (setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.mmd$" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

basically there is an alist (associative list / hashtable) called
`auto-mode-alist`.  That points extension -> to mode.  Extension looks
like it's a regular expression.

`cons` is a function that pre-pends an element to a list

`setq` means set quoted (which quotes auto-mode-list for you), otherwise
instead of assigning to the symbol auto-mode-alist, you will assign to
the results of evaluating that symbol...not what you want ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lists are built up from smaller pieces in Lisp.  The dot notation indicates those smaller pieces.

```
(a b c d e)                       ; a normal list
(a . (b . (c . (d . (e . nil))))) ; the same list in primitive form
```

An item of the form `(a . b)` syntax is called a *cons cell*; `a` is the *car* and `b` is the *cdr*.  (Those last terms come from the register names used to store them on the minicomputer Lisp was originally developed on, and are not otherwise meaningful.  *cons* is short for "construct".)  *cons cell* s are created with the `cons` function.  Notice that the behavior for prepending to a list falls naturally out of the internal format of a list, as shown above, and that *appending* to a list with `cons` will not do what one might naïvely expect.

*Alist* s are by historical convention plain *cons cell* s instead of full lists, originally for speed.

Comment: **Alist**:s are desinged to map one kind of element to another. They are not an historic artifact, and they have nothing to do with speed.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Yes, but alists would work just as well with proper lists instead of dotted pairs, because the car of a list would still be the key of the association. Therefore, dotted pairs for alists can arguably be called an optimisation to save the space of an additional nil to end the list and the time accessing the value with cadr instead of cdr would take.

Answer (score 14):

In lisp, on the low level, you can either have an simple value (a number or an atom) or a **dotted pair**,  or **cons cells**. (Let's ignore modern stuff like vectors...). On top of these, data structures like lists `(a b c)` are constructed.

An **alist** or **associative list**, is a plain list where each element itself (`a`, `b` et.c.) is a dotted pair. For example:

```
((foo . 10) (bar . 20))
```

You can search an alist using `assq` or `assoc`, a pair is returned. You can apply `car` and `cdr` to get the left or right part of the pair, respectively.

A plain list is cleverly constructed the above so that `(a b c)` is represented as `(a . (b . (c . nil)))` Typically, one does not have to know this to understand alist:s, but the internal printing mechanism can sometimes get thrown of. Concretely, `((foo . nil) (bar . 20))` is typically printed as `((foo) (bar . 20))`.

Answer (score 13):

Its the dotted pair notation. See [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node28.html) is also a nice description, the essence:

> A dotted list is one whose **last cons does not have nil for its cdr**,
>   rather some other data object (which is also not a cons, or the
>   first-mentioned cons would not be the last cons of the list).

This allows for example to specify a list whose last cons is a symbol, and this symbol then can point to another list, change at runtime, etc.